# all snap installed applications failed to launch with error udev_enumerate_scan_failed

Tags: snap, udev

So, I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.  I've loaded various software packages, and had everything working.  I rebooted this morning and now some of my applications won't launch... I even installed hiri this morning and it won't launch.  The icon just spins and then nothing.  When I try to launch from console I get udev_enumerate_failed.

Any suggestions?

```
oneeye@ubu:~$ hiri
udev_enumerate_scan failed
oneeye@ubu:~$ discord
udev_enumerate_scan failed
oneeye@ubu:~$ firefox
```

Comment: This appears to be only apps i've loaded with snapd - I am reloading snapd and will post progress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [snap keepassxc error udev\_enumerate\_scan failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963947/snap-keepassxc-error-udev-enumerate-scan-failed)

Comment: Nothing I've installed with snap works.  I've purged snap: sudo apt purge snapd and installed hiri and discord without snap and both are functioning.

Comment: Looks very similar David

Comment: I'm also seeing the same thing, and can't seem to find much on this at all

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug which has been [discussed](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/weird-udev-enumerate-error/2360?u=popey) and is being worked on. It's fixed in snapd 2.28.5 which is currently being tested.

You can also test it by updating the `core` snap to the beta channel where 2.28.5 is being tested prior to release.

`snap refresh core --beta`

However, you may prefer to stay on the stable channel, once 2.28.5 releases. You can easily switch core back to stable, thus.

`snap refresh core --stable`